# Accessing member of Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server object crashes exactly once

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

We are trying to access the `DefaultFile` member of an `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server` object. After a lot of debugging, it turns out that accessing the member crashes the first time, but can then be accessed just fine. Looking at the variable in a debug window returns an exception the first time, the correct value the second and all following times.

The first access of either `server.DefaultFile` or `server.DefaultLog` throws an exception like this:

```
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
 at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.BitStorage.SetBit(Int32 itemIndex, BitIndex bitIndex, Boolean value)
 at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.PropertyCollection.SetRetrieved(Int32 index, Boolean val)
 at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.AddObjectPropsFromDataReader(IDataReader reader, Boolean skipIfDirty, Int32 startColIdx, Int32 endColIdx)
 at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.ImplInitialize(String[] fields, OrderBy[] orderby)
 at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.Initialize(Boolean allProperties)
 at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.OnPropertyMissing(String propname, Boolean useDefaultValue)
 at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.PropertyCollection.GetValueWithNullReplacement(String propertyName, Boolean throwOnNullValue, Boolean useDefaultOnMissingValue)
 at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server.get_DefaultFile()
 at my function... etc etc
```

The first-access-crash is very concistent, so doing something terrible like below gets around the problem completely:

```
using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(sourceDatabaseConnectionString.ConnectionString))
{
    var svrConnection = new ServerConnection(sqlConnection);
    var server = new Server(svrConnection);

    // begin mega hack
    try
    {
        // crashes on first access
        var dummy = server.DefaultFile;
    }
    catch
    {
        // do absolutely nothing
    }
    // end mega hack

    // business as usual...
    var defaultFile = server.DefaultFile;
}
```

Of course, we don't like code like this (even if it's only in our internal tools) so any ideas of why this might be happening is welcome. Our only clue is that we've recently upgraded some instances of SQL Server 2012 to SQL Server 2014. We can sometimes get around the issue when running the code locally on a machine with SQL Server 2014 installed. The production machine that runs this code does not have an installation at all, but references DLLs. However, we can't find any differences in the versions used when debug printing the assembly versions while running the code.

Comment: First of all, SMO at the end of the date hit database, do you have permission to see `VIEW SERVER STATE/DEFINITION`?

Comment: Second: Is the default location for the user database files is the same as the system database files? If so then the DefaultFile and DefaultLog properties are never initialized. See [here](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/allen_white/archive/2009/02/19/finding-your-default-file-locations-in-smo.aspx), PowerShell equivalent (`if ($server.DefaultFile) { $server.DefaultFile } else { $server.InstallDataDirectory + '\' + 'Data' }`)

Answer (score 0):

I've seen similar messages when using an older version of SMO, especially when trying to use 2008R2 SMO to access 2012. Upgrading to the installs from 2008R2 Featurepack SP3 fixed my issues.

Check that there's not a more recent version of the Shared Management Objects + CLR Types + Native client driver that you could use.